# setup:di:compile error | source class generation does not exist

Tags: magento2, setup-di-compile

bin/magento setup:di:compile give me this error
Magento version 2.2.5

```
Source class "\Vendor\Module\Model\PostProductsInterface" for "\Vendor\Module\Model\PostProductsRepository" generation does not exist.
```

Comment: What version exact of magento

Comment: have you created the custom file in module? can you  share that file `PostProductsInterface`.

Comment: Magento version 2.2.5 - this file does not exist \Vendor\Module\Model\PostProductsInterface.php

Comment: Even I could not find `PostProductsRepository` and `PostProductsRepository` file in core magento 2. have you added any custom module?

Comment: it is under Vendor\Module\Api\Data\PostProductsInterface.php can it be?

Answer (score 1):

please check your project folder, 
if you don't see the class file maybe it's deleted or there is something wrong in your magento extension installation

if the class file exist, I think it could be 3rd extension that try inject that class. you can checking again 3rd extension that already install in your magento project

Comment: it is under Vendor\Module\Api\Data\PostProductsInterface.php can it be?

Comment: yes it can be,  if that's 3rd extension try to disable it,  and do di:compile again to see if there is difference.  and please notice for name class that you write,  incorrect one letter will cause calling wrong class name and it will cause error class not found or does not exist.

Comment: if i disable the custom module no error on compile but i cannot find the error in my custom module

Comment: is `\Vendor\Module\Model\PostProductsInterface` exist in your folder, and the path folder for `PostProductsInterface.php` is suitable based your description class ?

Comment: this file does not exist \Vendor\Module\Model\PostProductsInterface.php this is the only one with this name Vendor\Module\Api\Data\PostProductsInterface.php but this is interface not class interface PostProductsInterface

Answer (score -1):

remove this line from etc/di.xml solved

```
<preference for="Ea\Blog\Api\PostProductsRepositoryInterface" type="Ea\Blog\Model\PostProductsRepository"/>
```